# I want to make two arduino to communicate over different wifi. Is that possible?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, communication, network

I want to make any 2 Arduino module from different places to communicate over wifi. I really need to know if it possible? If yes, advice me more about it. I want send data from sensor module from one Arduino to another and vice versa. That's the basic idea. Do I need a third party services such as cloud services to make it happen? Or simply can send ovee wifi with the help of Ip adress. Sorry, I have less knowledge on this. Help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If they are on the same (wifi) network; then yes.

If you are on a different network, it would be more difficult. You would have to setup port forwarding on your router. Then you would have to somehow know the public IP address of the other router. These addresses can change from time to time with certain ISPs. I wouldn't advice doing this.

Instead I'd go with an third party service. For example Adafruits offers an MQTT server. I'd probably use this even if they are on the same network.